# Merge column to SummarizedExperiment from other dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, bioconductor

I have a `SummarizedExperiment` which looks like this:

`class: RangedSummarizedExperiment 
dim: 483731 485 
metadata(4): creationDate author BBMRIomicsVersion note
assays(1): data
rownames(483731): cg01707559 cg02004872 ... ch.22.47579720R ch.22.48274842R
rowData names(10): addressA addressB ... probeEnd probeTarget
colnames(485): 200397860027_R01C01 200397860027_R02C02 ... 200556930046_R03C01 200556930046_R06C02
colData names(946): STUDY_NUMBER SampleID ... Basename ID`

And I have a dataframe which looks like this:

`STUDY_NUMBER UPID    Testosterone    Estradiol   SHBG    Sex
1   UPID01  NA  NA  NA  male
3   UPID02  NA  NA  NA  male
3   UPID03  10.02   62  49.6    male
4   UPID04  NA  NA  NA  male
5   UPID05  NA  NA  NA  female`

I would like to merge this table (n rows = 3662), based on `STUDY_NUMBER`. So I used the following code:

`colData(aems450k1.MvaluesQCIMPplaqueSE) <- merge(colData(aems450k1.MvaluesQCIMPplaqueSE), AEDB_Q1_20180223_sex,
                 by.x = "STUDY_NUMBER", by.y = "STUDY_NUMBER", all.x = TRUE)`

Which results in the following `SummarizedExperiment` object:

`class: RangedSummarizedExperiment 
dim: 483731 485 
metadata(4): creationDate author BBMRIomicsVersion note
assays(1): data
rownames(483731): cg01707559 cg02004872 ... ch.22.47579720R ch.22.48274842R
rowData names(10): addressA addressB ... probeEnd probeTarget
colnames: NULL
colData names(952): STUDY_NUMBER SampleID ... Sex T_E2`

You'll note that `colnames` is now NULL. My question therefore:

*How can I prevent this from happening?*

My second question:

*Could this be happening because the order (based on `STUDY_NUMBER`) of the two dataframes are not the same?*

Many thanks,

Sander

Comment: Two things: 1) this question is better suited for the [bioc support site](https://support.bioconductor.org) 2) I think what is happening is that the merge is dropping the `rownames` of `colData` which is there the `colnames` come from for the `data`

Comment: Good suggestion: I shall put the question also on the bioConductor support site.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found the answer, also see: https://support.bioconductor.org/p/114113/#114117.

I think the issue is that the `colData` gets a different order than the `Assay` data, which should not happen. But if I `sort =` to the merge command everything is just fine, and I can add the colnames later on. So:

`dim(aems450k1.MvaluesQCIMPplaqueSE) 
aems450k1.MvaluesQCIMPplaqueSE 
colData(aems450k1.MvaluesQCIMPplaqueSE) <- merge(colData(aems450k1.MvaluesQCIMPplaqueSE), AEDB_Q1_20180223_sex, by = "STUDY_NUMBER", sort = FALSE) 
colnames(aems450k1.MvaluesQCIMPplaqueSE) <- aems450k1.MvaluesQCIMPplaqueSE$ID 
dim(aems450k1.MvaluesQCIMPplaqueSE)`

Which results in :

`class: RangedSummarizedExperiment 
dim: 483731 485 
metadata(4): creationDate author BBMRIomicsVersion note
assays(1): data
rownames(483731): cg01707559 cg02004872 ... ch.22.47579720R ch.22.48274842R
rowData names(10): addressA addressB ... probeEnd probeTarget
colnames(485): 8918692001_R01C01 8918692001_R02C01 ... 9221198166_R06C01 9221198166_R06C02
colData names(946): STUDY_NUMBER SampleID ... Basename ID`

Which is the correct order in the `colnames`. While without `sort =`, the order of colnames would be like `colnames(485): 9221198166_R06C02 9221198166_R06C01 ... 8918692001_R02C01 8918692001_R01C01`.

Does this makes sense?